# is there is any way to get xml value by tag in rapid xml using c++

Tags: c++, rapidxml

is there is any way to get the value of tag by its tagname in rapidxml using c++

```
<?xml version=\1.0\ encoding=\latin-1\?>
<book>example</book>
<book1>example1</book1>
```

i need to get the book value ie example and book1 value ....we can use this `doc.first_node()->value()`
get first node and next node but i need to is there is any way to get the value like `get by name`

Answer

```
xml_node<> *node = doc.first_node("book");
      cout <<< node->value() << "\n";
```

Comment: I don't know rapid xml, but what you are looking for is called "X-Path".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call first_node using a node name to be matched.  From [the docs](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#classrapidxml_1_1xml__node_7823e36687669e59c2afdf66334ef35a_17823e36687669e59c2afdf66334ef35a):

> function xml_node::first_node
>
> Synopsis
>
> xml_node* first_node(const Ch
>   *name=0, std::size_t name_size=0, bool case_sensitive=true) const;
>   Description
>
> Gets first child node, optionally
>   matching node name.
>
> Parameters
>
> name
>
> Name of child to find, or 0 to
>   return first child regardless of its
>   name; this string doesn't have to be
>   zero-terminated if name_size is
>   non-zero
>
> name_size
>
> Size of name, in
>   characters, or 0 to have size
>   calculated automatically from string
>
> case_sensitive
>
> Should name comparison
>   be case-sensitive; non case-sensitive
>   comparison works properly only for
>   ASCII characters
>
> Returns
>
> Pointer to found child, or 0 if not
>   found.

RapidXML does not support XPath for richer queries though.